# "a wottle of bine", "a can of boot reer" and "holed and sealed" - What types of speech errors are these?

Tags: terminology, errors

People often make these mistakes in speech on purpose, just for amusement. Sometimes, however, they are unintentional and prove even funnier.  In this case, is there a specific term for them?

e.g.

> - "belly jeans"  for  "jelly beans"
> - "a can of boot reer"  for  "a can of root beer"
> - "a wottle of bine"  for  "a bottle of wine"
> - "holed and sealed"  for  "soled and healed"
> - "cling spreaning"  for  "spring cleaning"

Comment: The usual name is a _Spoonerism_. Google on that name to see why.

Comment: Wouldn’t the third one have to be a _wattle of bine_ to make any sense? (But then, of course, it **would** make perfect sense, and actually be quite a sensible, imaginable thing.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In speech there wouldn't be much of a difference, would it?

Comment: None at all, no. But just like _belly jeans_ and _holed and sealed_, a _wattle of bine_ is (or could be) an actual thing (a wattle made of bine), whereas _wottle_ doesn’t have any meaning at all (like _reer_ or _spreaning_). Similar, a _boot rear_ would arguably be a thing, but _boot reer_ isn’t. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Janus, it's an audio phenomenon.  Spelling is secondary, I think.

Comment: Absolutely. The comic effect is just (sometimes) enhanced in writing if the spelling is altered to match the resulting words we actually _hear_. [ˈbuːʔ ɹʷiˑɹ] **sounds** funny, but _boot reer_ doesn’t **look** funny.

Comment: hum... does absolutely mean "yes" or "by no means"?

Comment: It means “yes, absolutely”. Otherwise, it would have been “absolutely not”.

Comment: Do you think I should edit ?

Comment: My wife and I like to say Root Beer kicks ass... it boots rear.

Comment: How about a "slip of the tongue", or - in some cases - a "Freudian slip" or a "parapraxis"...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you are referring to [spoonerism](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism)  : (from Wikipedia)

> - is an error in speech or deliberate play on words in which corresponding consonants, vowels, or morphemes are switched between two words in a phrase.

A similar error is [metathesis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)):

> - the re-arranging of sounds or syllables in a word, or of words in a sentence. Most commonly it refers to the switching of two or more contiguous sounds, known as adjacent metathesis or local metathesis:
>
>   - foliage > foilage
>   - cavalry > calvary

Comment: Spot on for both the specific and the general case. I like *worked/wrought*.

Comment: surely that is ablaut grade not metathesis?

Comment: As I recall, there's also a term for substituting the wrong but similar-sounding word.  (Though can't think of a good example just now.)

Comment: @HotLicks, that would be a malapropism:  "I just can't get the hang of physics, it's too conflagrated for my poor little brain."

Comment: Is pronouncing "nuclear" as "nuke-you-lar" an example of metathesis or might it be something else (since the syllables were not simply rearranged)?