# 2-word term for reversing phrases

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the 2-word term (3 syllables each, I think, and definitely Greek sounding/Greek roots) that describes the technique of reversing phrases or parts of phrases, e.g. " bred and born" instead of "born and bred"? I just can't remember it!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203212/a-wottle-of-bine-a-can-of-boot-reer-and-holed-and-sealed-what-types-of/203213#203213

Comment: @Josh61 That question is about Spoonerisms, which this is not.  Spoonerisms are a reversal of the first sound of two words to make a humorous new combination, supposedly inadvertently.  (Belly jeans for jelly beans.)  This is the reversal of two words which are normally a set expression, for no particular reason but common usage.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the phrase:

### Hysteron proteron

It is indeed a phrase of Greek origin consisting of two words of three syllables each, which means "latter before."

A reversal of logical order of elements in a phrase: “Sudden thunder and lightning drove them to shelter.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteron_proteron

Comment: Glad to have learned this - thx, Ahmad.