# Man who confused word order

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I'm trying to remember the name of a historical figure whose name has since entered the lexicon. He confused the order of words to say things like `it's all nuff and stonsense` for example. - I think he was a member of the clergy or a Don.

Comment: [Spilliam Archibald Wooner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Archibald_Spooner)

Comment: This is not a question about the English language.

Comment: It is about an English word. Is there somewhere more appropriate to ask this question?

Comment: *Spoonerisms*, *malapropisms* and assorted similar figures have been discussed extensively on this site in the past, [including here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203212/a-wottle-of-bine-a-can-of-boot-reer-and-holed-and-sealed-what-types-of/203213#203213)

Comment: It has always seemed to me that they should be called "Oonerspisms"....

Comment: Another view is that Spooner is the man who did *not* confuse the order. It is the rest of us who have it all bass ackward.

Answer (score 0):

[Spoonerism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spoonerism) definition:

> A reversal of sounds in two words, with humorous effect. Spoonerisms were named after William Spooner, an English clergyman and scholar of the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries. - Dictionary.com

Comment: Did you write this definition yourself? If not, you should edit your question to add the name of the source and a link to it. It seems to come from the "American Heritage New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy, Third Edition" according to the following web page: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spoonerism

Answer (score 0):

Spoonerism definition. A reversal of sounds in two words, with humorous effect. Spoonerisms were named after William Spooner, an English clergyman and scholar of the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries
Or are you thinking of malapropism? 
The mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often with unintentionally amusing effect, as in, for example, “dance a flamingo ” (instead of flamenco ). Named after Mrs Malaprop, a fictitious character

Comment: Was this meant to be an edit to your original post? I don't see why it's separate.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of the former but bonus points for the latter

Comment: @sumelic, is it a rep issue?

Comment: @DavidPell: There's not much of a rep issue, but it seems a bit confusing to have two answers that start the same way.

Comment: @sumelic, I agree, just wasn't sure whether you a higher reputation to edit the original answer

Comment: @DavidPell: Oh, I see I misunderstood your original comment. There are no rep requirements for editing your own posts.

Comment: Ajit: add this content to your first answer, and then delete this